# BadImageFormat exception when using OpenCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

briefly, our project is about taking attendance using face recognition with the openCV library in which we turned later into a specific DLL with our own adjustments (c++ program). also, we started using a demo code version of Affdex.dll (emotion recognition API C# program). the problem is when we tried to merging these to programs together an exception that we couldn't solve kept on occurring.[BadImageFormt exception]

both programs runs seperatly just fine. the openCV runs with x32 build and the Affdex program(emotion detection) runs with x64 build.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iffih.jpg

Comment: Well, there is your problem. One is 32bit, another 64bit.

Comment: we are unable to to merge them even when we made one of them a 64 build